# how to get json value that has no key

Tags: php, json, steam

i am using php to get the json values and have no problem looping though the data and echoing the SteamName, Level, Experience and more.  However I do not know how to echo the steamid number   7656119801319... per proile.

json file:

```
{
  "FURNACES": {},
  "PROFILE": {
    "76561198013191579": {
      "SteamName": "Cayos",
      "Level": 22,
      "Experience": 1592,
      "Agility": 22,
      "Strength": 22,
      "Intelligence": 22,
      "StatsPoints": 66,
      "SkillPoints": 2,
      "Skills": {
        "lumberjack": 20
      },
      "Preferences": {
        "ShowXPMessagePercent": 0.25,
        "ShowCraftMessage": true,
        "UseBlinkArrow": true,
        "AutoToggleBlinkArrow": true
      }
    },
    "76561198113765447": {
      "SteamName": "CaptainCheesy",
      "Level": 31,
      "Experience": 3576,
      "Agility": 31,
      "Strength": 70,
      "Intelligence": 70,
      "StatsPoints": 15,
      "SkillPoints": 5,
      "Skills": {
        "miner": 8,
        "lumberjack": 10,
        "hunter": 8
      },
      "Preferences": {
        "ShowXPMessagePercent": 0.25,
        "ShowCraftMessage": true,
        "UseBlinkArrow": true,
        "AutoToggleBlinkArrow": true
      }
    },
    "76561198141845337": {
      "SteamName": "Carrot",
      "Level": 3,
      "Experience": 409,
      "Agility": 3,
      "Strength": 3,
      "Intelligence": 3,
      "StatsPoints": 9,
      "SkillPoints": 3,
      "Skills": {},
      "Preferences": {
        "ShowXPMessagePercent": 0.25,
        "ShowCraftMessage": true,
        "UseBlinkArrow": true,
        "AutoToggleBlinkArrow": true
      }
    },
    "76561198012539649": {
      "SteamName": "Booglee",
      "Level": 3,
      "Experience": 110,
      "Agility": 3,
      "Strength": 3,
      "Intelligence": 3,
      "StatsPoints": 9,
      "SkillPoints": 3,
      "Skills": {},
      "Preferences": {
        "ShowXPMessagePercent": 0.25,
        "ShowCraftMessage": true,
        "UseBlinkArrow": true,
        "AutoToggleBlinkArrow": true
      }
    },
    "333228975": {
      "SteamName": "SYN Gaurd",
      "Level": 0,
      "Experience": 0,
      "Agility": 0,
      "Strength": 0,
      "Intelligence": 0,
      "StatsPoints": 0,
      "SkillPoints": 0,
      "Skills": {},
      "Preferences": {
        "ShowXPMessagePercent": 0.25,
        "ShowCraftMessage": true,
        "UseBlinkArrow": true,
        "AutoToggleBlinkArrow": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My PHP Code:

```
$url = 'C:\Users\plosey\Desktop\GameServers\Rust\steam\server_syn1\server\syn1\oxide\data\Hunt_Data.json';  //Url to the cars api
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content);
    foreach($json->PROFILE as $user) {
          echo $user->SteamName;  
          echo $user->NEED STEAM ID HERE;  // This is the line that is not correct.
}
```

so in short i would need to not only echo the SteamName but the Steamid number from the same profile.

Comment: Steamid number is the `key` to each profile. In order to access the key to each element when iterating through an array in PHP, use the syntax `$key => $value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to print id. $stremId will print your ID. You can replace it with any variable name.

```
$json = json_decode($json);
foreach($json->PROFILE as $streamId => $user) {
          echo $user->SteamName;
          echo $streamId;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
foreach($json->PROFILE as $user) {
```

use

```
foreach ($json->PROFILE as $steamid => $user) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($json->PROFILE as $key => $user) {
        echo $key .' => '.$user->SteamName."<br/>";
}
```